# Call Show windows side by side in C#

Tags: c#

Dumb question is there an easy way to clear to the desktop and then open two explorer windows and call the "Show windows side by side" task bar call ?  Just wondering if there is an api in an MS library way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of API functions can be easily found on MSDN Dev Center. Without having worked with the Win API much, this is where I would start:

1. Get collection of Windows with [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
2. Manipulate Window State with [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`TileWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633554%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TileWindows` WinAPI function via p/invoke to resize the desired windows to side-by-side.

To hide all other windows, just enumerate through them and minimise them.