# How can I open two windows on the left and right sides,likes win+←/→

Tags: c#

I want to open two windows on the left and right sides,this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace OpenWindows
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShellExecute((IntPtr)0, "open", "ms-settings:storagesense", "", null, 9);
            ShellExecute((IntPtr)0, "open", "msedge.exe", "www.google.com", null, 9);
        }
        [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(IntPtr hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirectory, int nShowCmd);
    }
}
```

This code can open two windows:setting-storage and edge.
I want to two windows on the left and right sides,likes win+←/→:

[click here to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7msG.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904520/open-url-from-windows-app-with-window-size

Comment: @Thescion Not sure how that linked question relates to the question. How would any of those answers help OP open these 2, not Chrome, apps at specific positions on screen?

Comment: @phuzi ok,  I missed the storage windows, but at least  it shows how to open chrome in different size, Edge is chromium base.

Comment: True, but it wouldn't open Edge or Chrome at a specific position on screen either

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747748/call-show-windows-side-by-side-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open URL from Windows app with window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904520/open-url-from-windows-app-with-window-size)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Thescion，@phuzi，@Thescion，@DanielBrughera answer my question.

I search google and coding, this code is work, bug not perfect，if you have another program，tell me please.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AllTest.OpenWindows
{
    class OpenWindows
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
            int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

            string arg = String.Format("--app=\"data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.resizeTo({0},{0});window.moveTo(0,0);window.location=\'http://www.google.com\';</script></body></html>\"", width / 2, height);

            ShellExecute((IntPtr)0, "open", "msedge", arg, null, 9);
            ShellExecute((IntPtr)0, "open", "ms-settings:storagesense", "", null, 9);

            var res = Process.GetProcessesByName("ApplicationFrameHost");
            IntPtr mhandle = res[0].MainWindowHandle;
            MoveWindow(mhandle, width / 2, 0, width / 2, height, true);
        }
        [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(IntPtr hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirectory, int nShowCmd);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).